# Бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "xxx"

Tags: c++, list, stl

не пойму, почему `remove_if` работает как надо, а `remove` выдают ошибку.

```
std::list<Element> items;

void RemoveElement(const Element & item)
{
    items.remove_if([&](const Element & value) {return item.GetName() == value.GetName(); });
    items.remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Что такое "xxx"? В сообщении об ошибке так и сказано?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823339/178988

Comment: @AnT, имя класса (`Element`) - вроде очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте оператор сравнения, вроде

```
bool operator==(const Element & item, const Element & value) 
{
    return item.GetName() == value.GetName(); 
}
```

Comment: Видимо хватит уже на сегодня с++. На такой простой ошибке запоролся. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "почему"? Я не знаю, что такое `"xxx"`, но скорее всего в сообщении об ошибке у вас ясно сказано, что оператора `==` для сравнения `Element` с `Element` у вас нет. Потому и ошибка.

Возможно также, что оператор-то вы написали, но, как часто бывает, пренебрежение правилами константной корректности сделало его невызываемым в данном случае.